# pickle faster than cPickle with numeric data?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

currently I'm working on image retrieval with Python. The keypoints and descriptors extracted from an image in this example are represented as `numpy.array`s. The first one of shape (2000, 5) and the latter of shape (2000, 128). Both containing only values of `dtype=numpy.float32`.

So, I was wondering which format to use in order to save my extracted keypoints and descriptors. I.e. I'm always saving 2 files: one for the keypoints and one for the descriptors - this counts as one step in my measurements. I compared `pickle`, `cPickle` (both with protocol 0 and 2) and NumPy's binary format `.pny` and the results are really confusing me:

[image]

I always thought `cPickle` is supposed to be faster than the `pickle` module. But especially the load time with protocol 0 really sticks out in the results. 
Does anyone have an explanation for this? Is it because I'm only using numeric data? Seems strange...

PS: In my code I'm basically looping 1000 times (`number=1000`) over each technique and average the measured time in the end:

```
    timer = time.time

    print 'npy save...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        numpy.save(npy_kp_path, kp)
        numpy.save(npy_descr_path, descr)
    t1 = timer()
    results['npy']['save'] = t1 - t0

    print 'npy load...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        kp = numpy.load(npy_kp_path)
        descr = numpy.load(npy_descr_path)
    t1 = timer()
    results['npy']['load'] = t1 - t0


    print 'pickle protocol 0 save...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(pkl0_descr_path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(descr, f, protocol=0)
        with open(pkl0_kp_path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(kp, f, protocol=0)
    t1 = timer()
    results['pkl0']['save'] = t1 - t0

    print 'pickle protocol 0 load...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(pkl0_descr_path, 'rb') as f:
            descr = pickle.load(f)
        with open(pkl0_kp_path, 'rb') as f:
            kp = pickle.load(f)
    t1 = timer()
    results['pkl0']['load'] = t1 - t0


    print 'cPickle protocol 0 save...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(cpkl0_descr_path, 'wb') as f:
            cPickle.dump(descr, f, protocol=0)
        with open(cpkl0_kp_path, 'wb') as f:
            cPickle.dump(kp, f, protocol=0)
    t1 = timer()
    results['cpkl0']['save'] = t1 - t0

    print 'cPickle protocol 0 load...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(cpkl0_descr_path, 'rb') as f:
            descr = cPickle.load(f)
        with open(cpkl0_kp_path, 'rb') as f:
            kp = cPickle.load(f)
    t1 = timer()
    results['cpkl0']['load'] = t1 - t0


    print 'pickle highest protocol (2) save...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(pkl2_descr_path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(descr, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        with open(pkl2_kp_path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(kp, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    t1 = timer()
    results['pkl2']['save'] = t1 - t0

    print 'pickle highest protocol (2) load...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(pkl2_descr_path, 'rb') as f:
            descr = pickle.load(f)
        with open(pkl2_kp_path, 'rb') as f:
            kp = pickle.load(f)
    t1 = timer()
    results['pkl2']['load'] = t1 - t0


    print 'cPickle highest protocol (2) save...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(cpkl2_descr_path, 'wb') as f:
            cPickle.dump(descr, f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        with open(cpkl2_kp_path, 'wb') as f:
            cPickle.dump(kp, f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    t1 = timer()
    results['cpkl2']['save'] = t1 - t0

    print 'cPickle highest protocol (2) load...'
    t0 = timer()
    for i in range(number):
        with open(cpkl2_descr_path, 'rb') as f:
            descr = cPickle.load(f)
        with open(cpkl2_kp_path, 'rb') as f:
            kp = cPickle.load(f)
    t1 = timer()
    results['cpkl2']['load'] = t1 - t0
```

Comment: I just noticed this today myself and found your question, I get at least an order of magnitude difference. pickle is definitely faster than cpickle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (binary representation of) the numeric data of an `ndarray` is pickled as one long string. It appears that `cPickle` is indeed much slower than `pickle` in unpickling large strings from protocol 0 files. Why? My guess is that `pickle` makes use of well-tuned string algorithms from the standard library and `cPickle` has fallen behind.

The observation above is from playing with Python 2.7. Python 3.3, which uses a C extension automatically, is faster than either module on Python 2.7, so apparently the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the solution with Python 3.3. My example uses ideed 2.7. Will check out 3.3

Comment: @pklip But why would you insist on using protocol 0? Protocol 2 is fast according to your timings.

Comment: Of course I will use protocol 2 as I won't need a "textually readable" file. I was just wondering and curious to try out 3.3 in general :)