# What's the fastest way to save/load a large list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, io, save

What's the fastest way to save/load a large list in Python 2.7?  I apologize if this has already been asked, I couldn't find an answer to this exact question when I searched...

More specifically, I'm testing out methods for simulating something, and I need to compare the result from each method I test out to an exact solution.  I have a Python script that produces a list of values representing the exact solution, and I don't want to re-compute it every time I run a new simulation.  Thus, I want to save it somewhere and just load the solution instead of re-computing it every time I want to see how good my simulation results are.

I also don't need the saved file to be human-readable.  I just need to be able to load it in Python.

Comment: you can pickle it https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html , numpy.dump  or http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html if you want to use numpy arrays

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hmm, ok thanks!  Do you know if any of these methods is noticeably faster than the other?  I also wonder if it would speed up or slow down the code if I modify it to produce the reference solution in numpy array format instead of a list format.

Comment: If you are worried about performance maybe you should be using numpy to do all your work

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the part where I produce the solution, since that only happens once.  It's just the loading part that will happen many times.  I'm guess I'm wondering if it'll be faster to load a numpy array as opposed to a list?

Comment: absolutely, loading a numpy array would be faster than unpickling a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using np.load and tolist is significantly faster than any other solution:

```
In [77]: outfile = open("test.pkl","w")   
In [78]: l = list(range(1000000))   

In [79]:  timeit np.save("test",l)
10 loops, best of 3: 122 ms per loop

In [80]:  timeit np.load("test.npy").tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 20.9 ms per loop

In [81]: timeit pickle.load(outfile)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.86 s per loop

In [82]: outfile = open("test.pkl","r")

In [83]: timeit pickle.load(outfile)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.88 s per loop

In [84]: cPickle.dump(l,outfile)
....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 
273 ms per loop    
In [85]: outfile = open("test.pkl","r")
In [72]: %%timeit
cPickle.load(outfile)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 
539 ms per loop
```

In python 3 numpy is far more efficient if you use a numpy array:

```
In [24]: %%timeit                  
out = open("test.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(l, out)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 27.3 ms per loop

In [25]: %%timeit
out = open("test.pkl","rb")
pickle.load(out)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 52.2 ms per loop

In [26]: timeit np.save("test",l)
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop

In [27]: timeit np.load("test.npy")
100 loops, best of 3: 2.35 ms per loop
```

If you want a list it is again faster to call tolist and use np.load:

```
In [29]: timeit np.load("test.npy").tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 37 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is this with `pickle` or `cPickle`?

Comment: seems relatively inline with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833124/pickle-faster-than-cpickle-with-numeric-data If thats the case then I'd probably suggest that OP goes with numpy if they're are working with numpy already, and cPickle if they aren't. - But it really seems to be personal preference.

Comment: in my case, numpy got similar speed with cPickle.
``` pk.dump( a, open('a.pickle', 'wb'), pk.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

Answer (score 3):

As PadraicCunningham has mentioned, you can pickle the list.

```
import pickle

lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

with open('file.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(lst, pickle_file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

this loads the list into a file.

And to extract it:

```
import pickle

with open('file.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_load:
    lst = pickle.load(pickle_load)
print(lst) # prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` bit is optional, but is normally recommended. Protocols define how pickle will serialise the object, with lower protocols tending to be compatible with older versions of Python.

It's worth noting two more things:

There is also the `cPickle` module - written in C to optimise speed. You use this in the same way as above.

Pickle is also known to have some insecurities (there are ways of manipulating how pickle deserialises an object, which you can manipulate into making Python do more or less whatever you want). As a result, this library shouldn't be used when it will be opening unknown data. In extreme cases you can try out a safer version like `spickle`: https://github.com/ershov/sPickle

Other libraries I'd recommend looking up are `json` and `marshall`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The security part shouldn't be an issue for me since I will be the only one with access to the data (unless my computer gets hacked or something).  Do you know if cPickle is likely the fastest solution?

Comment: I can't say what the fastest solution is as I've not run the tests. but as `cPickle` is written in `C`, it will be a good deal faster than most things written in `Python` (Most of the libraries you'd be using). So I would say it's a good bet.

Comment: @nukeguy, it's also worth mentioning that there aren't many other ways to store pure `Python` objects without manipulating them into a workable format, using `pickle`/`cPickle` means that you don't have to do any manipulation or parsing and can just save as is. All this will obviously factor into processing time.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some profiling of many methods (except the numpy method) and pickle/cPickle is very slow on simple data sets.  The fastest way depends on what type of data you are saving.  If you are saving a list of strings and/or integers.  The fastest way that I've seen is to just write it directly to a file using a for loop and `','.join(...)`; read it back in using a similar for loop with `.split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Python object serialization,`pickle` and `cPickle` 
http://pymotw.com/2/pickle/

`pickle.dumps(obj[, protocol])`
If the protocol parameter is omitted, protocol 0 is used. If protocol is specified as a negative value or HIGHEST_PROTOCOL, the highest protocol version will be used.